# Share files over Samba from a remote mount over ssh. Good idea? Best practice?

Tags: ssh, samba

I need some users working from their homes to access lot of files (not very  big ones, but many of them), easily over 18TB of files. The problem is that those users are not working 100% for us, and we need a way to isolate their machines as much as possible from us.

I know there are other ways of achieving this, but I'd like to explore this one.

My idea is:

Give them a small virtual machine to run locally on their computers, this VM will be configured to:

- Be low on resources (I'm thinking on a minimal CentOS install to take
  just maybe 256MB of RAM or so).
- Be locked, encrypted, and unable to connect with anything but our    server.
- Connect to our network over SSH or VPN
- Mount a remote shared folder once connected
- Share that folder with the Host.
- Only way of connection from the Hypervisor side would be through the Samba share.

That way, the user would access the shared folder and work as usual, but we will have full control over the machine connecting with us. (The user computer is not property of our company)

To be precise about my question, I'd like to know if this sounds too crazy or maybe someone knows if I will have trouble with it?

What would be the best approach to achieve this if you don't find this correct?

Answer (score 0):

You won't have full control over the machine, as you need to tell the users the encryption passphrase, otherwise they can't start the machine. With this, they will have full control over the VM as well.

Just give them access to some RDP server they can connect to in order to work on files (behind a VPN) - you'll have much more control over this.

---

Edit: Some more explanation why I don't think your solution would be worth the effort.

First, let's consider a normal VPN and direct connection to your CIFS server. You usually can firewall the VPN endpoint in a way that it will allow only connections to your CIFS server on the CIFS ports. The CIFS server will then make sure the client can only access only the resources it has permissions for.

Your VM solution will allow basically the same thing, with the  difference that it will proxy the CIFS connection through a Samba service. Granted, this *is* an additional layer of security, as the client will have a more difficult time to attack potential CIFS implementation vulnerabilities on your server (this is not necessarily impossible though). However, the price for this is really high as your environment is very complex and error prone and also support-intensive, as you need to actively unlock your encrypted VM whenever the client machine has to be restarted for whatever reason (and quite frankly, I wouldn't allow anyone access to my private machine for that purpose!).

Adding a CIFS proxy on your side would indeed work and lead to a much more maintainable environment with the  same end result - just have the clients VPN to that proxy instead of the original CIFS server.

NB: Doing all this is all nice and fine, but unfortunately, it does nothing to protect you from the real, most likely danger in that whole scenario, which is the possibility that the client gets infected with malware, e.g. ransomware. Whichever way you implement this, the client will have write access to some CIFS share, and the only way to protect you from this is to keep regular and reliable backups and to test them!

Comment: As above, give users RDP access without being able to copy out of the session.

Comment: RDP is not an option, since users need gpu performance and input devices to draw (wacom tablets).

Comment: Both are possible over RDP (likely with the Wacom reduced to mouse functionality, but this will be the case with your VM idea as well). Granted, you'll need a powerful terminal server for that, but still possible. Oh, and GPU acceleration with desktop virt in Linux isn't very powerful in my experience.

Comment: Maybe i did not explained myself well enough. Clients are using windows 7 and Windows 10, mostly workstations with high-end GPU's. Wacom functionality is needed. I want the vm just to connect to our network and expose a share to the client PC with our data.

Comment: Also, placing the passphrase would not be an issue, since we can be the ones connecting to their pcs and entering it. Once the VM is turned on, they would not need to switch it off at all.

Comment: What would you gain by this absurdly complex contraption that you can't achieve with a simple VPN? I don't get this at all...

Comment: We need to avoid any direct connection from computers not owned and mantained by us. I know VPN will work, but i'd like to add a layer in between our network and their computers.

Comment: Maybe i can add a server on our side and isolate it from the network... and then the remote workers connect to that server... wich itself connects through vpn to the files.... that would be easier isnt it? (again, as of now im exploring my options)

Comment: @JorgeJiménez: See my edits for my thoughts on this.

Comment: @Sven: Thanks a lot on your comments! - Indeed it seems like a bit troublesome to go over the vm approach instead of securing a firewalled server. I guess we will take that route instead.

Comment: However, to be precise, my goal is not only security (ransomware is not an issue for us, we are covered), but also compliance, since we don't want any remote machine to be associated with our network. All of our software is licensed, but that may not be the case with these computers (it's pretty expensive for a freelance or small company, and we can expect some of them may use unlicensed or pirated software)... NDA's and MCA's are'nt always a reflect of reality.